# Does Xen need an XServer for graphical display?

Tags: linux, xen

I'm trying to create a very small ISO, which is bootable and brings up a DomU such as Windows 7 using Xen. I want to setup the minimal number of packages in the small ISO, therefore I'm wondering if Xen does need an XServer setup for graphical display, or can it utilize display independently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While bahamant's answer is true (xen does not need a gui, since you can handle it via CLI) you are propably asking for the management-tool `virt-manager`.

There are two ways to use it:

- a) Install it in the XEN-Dom0 and run it from there (requires installation of X11)
- b) Just install virt-manager an an admin-workstation and run it from there

In case a) you do not need runlevel 5, but you need the relevant X11-libaries, so you can do `ssh -X YOURDOM0 "virt-manager"`.

In case b) you do not even need X11 on your Dom0 - which possibly suits your needs.

If you need a VNC-connection to your DomU (e.g. to access it before the OS is fully up and running) you will propably have to add the following lines to your DomU-configuration-file to access the VNC-display (which is normally bound to localhost):

```
vnc=1
vncunused=1
vnclisten="logical IP for accessing the GUI of your DomU"
vncpasswd="optional VNC-password"
```

Answer (score 0):

Xen does not need an X server.

Comment: True, but this was not the question.